# Firefox drops the session variable

Tags: php, firefox, session

I just have a simple session start and assigned a session variable on login.  However when I switch pages, the session variable does not stick in Firefox. I can still see the session is there but just not the variable. In IE7, IE8, Chrome, and Safari, it works and sticks. What is happening in Firefox and how can I fix it?

Here is a snippet of the code.

```
session_start();

if ($_POST['login']) :
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a client side issue. Probably Firefox does not send the session cookie.

Comment: I don't think so as it seems to only affect my code...i have other sites that utilizes sessions and it works fine in firefox...But again, I don't see anything wrong with my code so therefore hard to figure out what is really wrong and especially because it works in the other browsers that I've mentioned...

Comment: Did you check domain and expiry of your session cookies? Did you compare the raw HTTP request headers?

Comment: Yes I did...as mentioned above, the session is still intact..just the variable gets dropped..  How do you compare the "raw HTTP request headers"?

Comment: If FF would send the same request as the other browsers, the server would most likely restore the session vars properly. I don't think your servers detects FF and misbehaves intentionally. The raw request can be seen in your logs (if logging is configured approprietely) or with PHP's `http_get_request_headers()`.